# Physical Situations of Specific Stress Energy Tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-spin, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, modified-gravity

I'm having trouble picturing what the physical situation of a non-symmetric stress would be. Say I have a stress tensor $T_{ab} = \begin{pmatrix} T_{00} & T_{01}& 0 & 0 \\ 0&T_{11}&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$

What physical situation(s) (classical and quantum) would represent this tensor where the energy flux is non zero but momentum density is zero?

edit: I cannot create a new tag for Einstein-Cartan so I will leave GR as a tag.

Comment: In General Relativity (which I'm mentioning due to the tags on the question), it is mandatory for the stress tensor to be symmetric. That is both by definition of the stress tensor and by imposition of the Einstein equations.

Comment: Yes, that is case for the torsion free or zero spin tensor condition. I guess if those are non-zero it would be Einstein-Cartan. Should I remove the tag of general relativity?

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to remove the tag. I'd say just specifying you don't necessarily mean GR is enough. I added the modified-gravity tag to account for that

Comment: Are you familiar with Hawking-Ellis (Segre-Plebanski) classification of Stress energy tensor? Check this article: https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.00865

Comment: @KP99 I was not aware of the classifications. Thank you for the paper! It helped a lot :)

Comment: @PhysicsStudent101 No problem :)